# We are sorry but the Host could not be saved

Tags: dns, zerigo

I have the following DNS settings for the site `fls.net`:

[image]

I am switching my domain registrar to know use the Zergio name servers, as opposed to Hostgator, to resolve the DNS. I would like all of our mail to go the same IPS listed in the above diagram.

When I try to enter the IP of the priority 0 MX record in my Zerigo UI I get the  following error:

`We are sorry but the Host could not be saved.`
`The following problems were found:`
`Data must be a valid domain name`

My question is, If I am trying to route all the new Zerigo MX records I am creating for the domain *fls.net* to the old MX records with IPS 69.28.248.225 and 198.20.73.147 how am I to do that if the data only takes domain names?

If I put `mailst1.fls.net.` as the data for the MX record, how is going to know to resolve that address to the Hostgator mail IP, if I am now bypassing the whole hostgator name servers and using Zerigo instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I didn't understand that MX Records just map to domain names, at least in the Zerigo interface.

So I just did the following

created an MX record which maps to `mail.fls.net`

And then created a mail.fls.net A record which maps to the Hostgator mail IP